# MariaDB Multi-source Replication SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER

Tags: replication, mariadb

When an error occurs on a slave while executing a statement from the master, it is sometimes useful to use SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER variable to skip the execution of the query, like this:

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;
START SLAVE;
```

While this works for main replication thread, I wonder how this is possible on a MariaDB Multi-source replication thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the *default_master_connection* variable for the session to make it work for a specific multi-source connection:

```
STOP SLAVE 'src1';
SET @@default_master_connection = 'src1';
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;
START SLAVE 'src1';
SET @@default_master_connection = '';
```

Comment: While your answer is correct and I voted up, I would add that one should always store and then restore the old value of @@default_master_connection. This may present some kinds of human errors.

Comment: You're right. However @@default_master_connection variable is defined only for the current session and will be reset when you reconnect.

Comment: Yes, but the current session is supposed to be root, so I do everything I can to avoid possible mistakes in production. Personal opinion, of course.